# TextView onMeasure caused NullPointerException

Tags: android, textview

I have a layout created by hard code in my project,I have seen some logs like below,but I can't reappear that.I have setLayoutParams() in the TextView,but it is not useful.This layout is a detail page ,I have defined some ids for these views and I had copy this layout for another detail page,so the two pages used same ids for their views,and the layout is same ,is this conflict ?I need some help,THX!

`java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.widget.TextView.onMeasure(TextView.java:6559)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16552)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5130)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1052)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:590)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16552)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:689)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:473)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16552)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:689)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:473)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16552)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1226)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:590)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16552)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5130)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16552)
    at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1226)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:326)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16552)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16552)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5130)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16552)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5130)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16552)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16552)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16552)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5130)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16552)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5130)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16552)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5130)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2340)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16552)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1927)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1124)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1306)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1011)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5638)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:786)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:772)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5143)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

Comment: There's not much to go on here. If you tell us the version of Android that was running to generate this stack trace, we could look at the source for TextView and find out what happens at line 6559. Also, showing us your code would help, particularly if you could reduce your code to an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: sorry，it is 4.4.4 for this log

Comment: Well, without the specific release number (including what device/emulator it's running on) that's still a little ambiguous. However, at least in some versions of 4.4.4, line 6559 is close to code that will throw a NPE if the layout parameters are `null`. My guess is that you are not constructing your view hierarchy correctly; specifically that you are not correctly setting the layout parameters.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice,I have checked my code that each TextView in this layout had set correct layout parameters.I get these logs by third party server and I didn't know how to get the release number for android version.I found I have defined some same ids for views in two layout,these ids used for View.setId(),is this conflict?My code is too large for the view hierarchy construct,if you have some time ,I wish to send a email to you with my code.Thank you .

Comment: Having the same id on different views is not going to cause this kind of problem. I'd suggest that you try to use the debugger to examine what's going on at the moment the exception is thrown.